# Customize Html Email font-family

Tags: css, fonts, html-email

I want to customize `font-family` in html file to use in email. Unfortunately I can't use most of `font-family`. Is there any one who has solutions for it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a `font-family` declaration using inline CSS, all email clients will render the fonts using systems fonts as a web page would.

Eg:

```
<td style="'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;">
    some text
</td>
```